# Inserting bullets and numbering to text

Tags: cocoa, string

Using the Cocoa Framework, how can I add bullets and numbering to text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For bullets you can add UTF-8 characters to your strings.

From the cocoa dev website:
http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?UniCode

```
NSString *aBullet = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\u2022"];
```

You can find list of UTF-8 characters here: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl

Be aware that they are generally expressed as a hexidecimal. Its under General Punctuation.